# rebot command not generating output.xml

Tags: robotframework

I have a rebot command usage which otherwise works fine for following;

rebot --reporttitle "Test Report" --outputdir /logs --output output.xml --report report.html /logs/api.xml /logs/ff.xml /logs/chrome.xml

But one of the test suites doesn't have the api tests hence there is no api.xml getting generated. For this rebot commands doesn't generated the output.xml. Is there a way to pass the xml files as optionals or not necessary to be checked by rebot?

Comment: You could create a script to wrap rebot, but I strongly suggest you go with Bryan Oakley's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You need to put that logic in a script that calls rebot. Though, if all of your logs (and only your logs) are written to `/logs`, you can use `/logs/*.xml` on the command line and it will process all of the .xml files in that directory.